# How to generate a list of posts published on current day?

Tags: get-posts

I want to create a page labeled "Today's News" which displays a simple bulleted list of all posts published on the current day and grab the current date based on the server's date/time. Is this feasible?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts)

```
$day = date('j');
query_posts( "day=$day&order=ASC" );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this feasible?

Yes.

---

[`get_posts();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) is your best friend. No need to modify the query or run a new one.

```
// Call it with the date you need as input argument
function wpse28632_get_daily_posts( $date = null )
{
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'order_by' => 'post_date' ) ); // additional arguments - see Codex
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        if ( $date == $post->post_date )
            echo "<li>{$post}</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: What is there are thousands of posts - should you get all of them just to list today's ones?

Comment: If there are about hundreds of thousand, both visitors **&** posts, then you could try to do a direct SQL query for a better performance. Else the index just works fine. Also: `get_posts();` is nothing else than a `new WP_Query`. This has two advantages: 1) It's easier than doing a new query, saving the `object` and picking the stuff you need and the args are partly shared with query, but just simplified.  Imo `array` is easier to understand for most than `object`. 2) Less chance to make failures. If you don't save the result in some var, it will be performed, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Darhazer. Btw: Read [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) for better insights. Andrej fetched it up pretty well.